# Specific aggregated query using mongoose / mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need help to achieve the following task.

I want to query all documents from a mongodb using mongoose of type TokenBalance. The schema looks like this

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema(
{
    address  : { type: String, index: true },
    ethervalue: {type: Number, required:true},
    balances : []
},
{ timestamps: true }
);
```

The balances [] Array inside that schema holds multiple objects of this structure

```
{address: addresshash, symbol: someSymbol, balance: somebalance, usdvalue: usdvalueOfBalance}
```

What I need, is to query all Docs of Type TokenBalance within a timespan that is given and then from all of these documents sum the usdvalues grouped by symbols.

For example the output I need should look like this:

```
[
 {symbol: BTC, balance: 100.000},
 {symbol: ETC, balance: 120.000}
 ...
]
```

I'm having difficulties writing the correct aggregation for this. Especially I don't know how to group by the documents "balances" array and its symbols and sum the values.

I hope my question is clear and someone could help me.

Thank you in advance

Comment: nobody able to help?